# C programming. Issue with unsigned integer evaluation

Tags: c

In C programming I have this problem :

```c
int v = 0XFFFD;
unsigned z=1;
```

Evaluate the expressions:

```
a) (v+1)/2  
b) -1 > z
```

In the problem book, for
a) the answer is `-1`, and for
b) the answer is `1`.

Can anybody explain why?
Because in my opinion for
a) I think the answer is `32767`, and for
b) is `0`.

Comment: Look up signed and unsigned number representations

Comment: In expression 2, the unsigned quantity -1 is converted to a signed quantity. Since it is negative, it will "wrap around" to `~0` or `0xffffffff`

Comment: This question is testing your understanding of how integers are represented in the computer and understanding how many bits are in an `int`. Look up "two's complement integers". In this case, `int v` has a value of `0xFFFD`. Based upon the information you've given, I assume your compiler has 16-bit integers. So `0xFFFD` as an `int` is actually a negative number. An `int` in this case has a range of -32768 to 32767. `unsigned` means all of the bits represent a non-negative number. So the range is 0 to 65535.

Comment: Thank you very much. This things nobody says in the books. I can only find out from pro like you.

Comment: Oh it's all out there. You just didn't find it or didn't recognize it when you saw it. You just have to now the right question to search for.

Comment: Are you using a 16-bit compiler such as Turbo C for DOS?  Or are you using a 32-bit compiler or a 64-bit compiler (almost anything else).  The answers will differ (radically) if `sizeof(int) == 2 && CHAR_BIT == 8` compared with what you get if `sizeof(int) == 4 && CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1 :**
By default type of int is signed that means compile will check sign bit and if sign bit is one means output will be negative.

```
int v = 0XFFFD
```

How `v` will be stored in memory,if its a little endian it looks like below

```
    -------------------------
    | 1111 1111  | 1111 1101 |
    -------------------------
   MSB                      LSB
                             v
```

As you can see sign bit(15th bit, in case of short int) is one, and negative number are stored in memory as two's compliment. and two's compliment of `v` i is

```
 one's compliment =>  0000 0000 |  0000 0010
                                          +1
                      -----------------------
                      0000 0000 |  0000 0011 => 3 and since sign bit is one  that's why v is -3
```

When you are doing `(v+1)/2 == (-3+1)/2 => -1`

**Case 2 :**

```
unsigned z = 1;
```

Let's say statement looks like

```
printf("%d\n", -1 > z);
```

Here while performing any operation between two operands you should be aware of consequences of if operands types are different.

```
 -1  >  z
 |      |           => comparing different operands
signed unsigned       (one is signed and other one unsigned) => Implicit type conversion will happen i.e implicitly signed gets promoted into unsigned by compiler)
                            ||
                        65535 > 1 => true => pints 1 
                        |
               (-1 is signed and its converted into unsigned and unsigned equivalent of -1 is 65535 in case of shot integer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This things nobody says in the books. I can only find out from pro like you.

Comment: No, assignment in C is by value not by representation. There are a lot of implementation dependent choices that lead to the result that you are suggesting for "1."

Comment: @JensGustedt yes I agree with you about implementation dependent point in case 1. In windows compiler default `int` is of `2 bytes` & on linux platform it's of `4 bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

C defines its integer math operation functionally, not as bit patterns.  Thinking of a number in bits may be useful, but let us see what C specifies.

---

```
int v = 0XFFFD;
```

`int` must be at  least encode [-32767 ... 32767].  OP's case appears to use minimally sized `int`.

`0XFFFD` is a *hexadecimal constant* with the value of 65,533.  Its type is the first that it fits in: `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long ...`.  In this case it is `unsigned`.

`int v = some_unsigned` requires a conversion of the `unsigned` to `int`.  When the source is out-of-range of an `int`, it is *implementation defined* what happens.  A common result is a "wrap-around" by subtracting 2<sup>16</sup>.  Code could instead assign `INT_MAX`.  It is *implementation defined*.  Apparently code is wrapping in OP's case.

```
int v = 65533 - 65536; // -3
// or maybe
int v = 32767; // Uncommon implementation defined result.
```

`(v+1)/2` is simply then `(-3 + 1)/2` --> -1.

Had the *hexadecimal constant* fit in an `int`, perhaps on a platform with a 32-bit `int`, `(65533 + 1)/2` would have been 32767 as considered by OP.

---

`unsigned z = 1;` is simple.  `z` has the value of 1.

`-1 > z` compares an `int` `-1` to an `unsigned`.  Compares are done with the same type.

`unsigned` is higher *rank* than `int`, so `-1` is converted to an `unsigned` and its value is changed by adding `UINT_MAX +1`.  `-1 + UINT_MAX +1` --> `UINT_MAX`.

Now the compare is like `UINT_MAX > 1` which is true. A compare result is an `int`, either 0 or 1.  The result here is an `int` 1.

The result is independent of the range of `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

1. because `int` is signed integer, 0xfffd equals -3. So `(v+1)/2` gets -1
2. signed integer is automatically converted (coercion) to unsigned integer
   if you compare signed integer with unsigned integer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This things nobody says in the books. I can only find out from pro like you.

Answer (score 0):

*Short story*: your book seems to be quite bad.

Never, ever, initialize an `int` (a signed type) with a value that can be unsigned such as a hexadecimal constant.

*Long story*:

The results of "1." depends on a lot of things. First, it would be important to know the number of significant bits of `int`. In the following let us assume that it is 16 bit, otherwise the questions is even more senseless.

If it is 16, then the hex constant on the right side is greater than the maximal `int`. Since integer constants in C always are positive, it doesn't fit into an `int` and thus it has type `unsigned int`.

Thus a conversion of an `unsigned` to `int` must be done for the intialization. This is "implementation defined" that is your compiler is allowed to do what pleases, as long as it is documented.

Many compilers do a "lazy" conversion, that is, they just chose the value that has the same *representation* as the `unsigned` value. If your machine has two's representation for `int` (again an implementation dependent choice) the result would be a negative value, most likely `-3`.

So, the real answer for "1." is: *it depends*. An introductory book should never ask a question in that way, simply suggesting that the result of that operation is depending on the integer representation. Integer representation only comes in by accident.